# ¿Cómo poder llamar a un html y que se cargue con un archivo específico?

Tags: javascript, html5

Quisiera saber si es posible utilizar alguna función en la que se pueda indicar el .html a visualizar y de paso indicarle que archivo .json le va a dar el contenido.

```
 <div class="tarjeta-producto">
    <img class="img-trj-prod" src="../RSC/DELL_INSPIRON_G3.jpg" alt="DELL_INSPIRON_G3">
       <div class="titulo-trj">
          <a href="javascript:abrirItem('URL_html','URL_json')"><h3>prueba</h3></a>
       </div>
       <div class="info-trj">
          <label class="precio-trj">$ 450.00</label>
          <i class="agrega-carro icon-cart-plus"></i>
       </div>
 </div>
```

este es lo que tengo momentanemente en javascript:

```
function abreItem(url_html,url_json){
    this.url_html = url_html;
    this.url_json = url_json;

    window.open(url_html,"_self");
}
```

¿cómo se puede decirle al html que se va a visualizar que a la par ejecute una lectura del archivo .json que se introdujo como parámetro la primera ocasión?

Si me pueden guiar les agradezco muchísimo.

Comment: Puedes enviar la ubicación del archivo como parámetro a la función, algo como `<a href="javascript:ejecutarHTML('ruta/archivo.extension')"><h3>prueba</h3></a>`; si necesitas otro parámetro, solo agrégalo, separado por coma.

Comment: claro si tenia pensado eso solo que creería que fueran dos parámetros que tenga esa función con el fin de también especificarle la ruta del archivo.json

Comment: Entonces sería algo como: `<a href="javascript:ejecutarHTML('ruta/archivo.html', 'ruta/archivo.json')"><h3>prueba</h3></a>`